# How can i modify React JS state through chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I'm building a **Chrome extension** for Whatsapp Web to add some features. One of these features includes modifying the contact's name in the chat list.

The chat list is a **virtualized list**, so about 15 contacts are displayed at a time. I have added an event listener on scroll, but the DOM is modifying the wrong contacts while scrolling.

I thought if I can modify the contact directly from the React state of the Whatsapp web application it would solve the problem. But how can do this through chrome extension?

I know it's possible because I've seen other extensions do.

Comment: Use MutationObserver, [example](/a/39334319).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the sugestion. I tried this code: http://pastie.org/p/0SfKT8q8PErMPmC1ydPPDR. But had the same problem. Some wrong contacts are updated.

Comment: Inspect and debug the other extensions in the built-in devtools in the browser.